# Can you start bounty here on physics meta if your question didn't receive enough attention for example?

Tags: discussion, bounty, meta

Can you start bounty here on physics meta if your question didn't receive enough attention for example as you can do on the other websites in the network outside meta?

Comment: No, you cannot. Which question of yours didn't receive enough attention?

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the downvotes. It is a legitimate question.

Comment: Since no to its earned or gained on Meta, how can one offer a bounty?

Comment: @KyleKanos One possibility would be using main site rep.

Comment: I'm not sure how looking at your profile helps.  Except for questions closed as duplicates, all your questions have accepted answers.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero How this is relevant to my question exactly?

Comment: it is relevant to your previous comment, wherein you suggest people check your profile for downvotes.  Your profile shows that all your questions received enough attention for you to accept an anwer, or were duplicates of questions already asked.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I see what do you mean. I told Blue to see my profile, because I have many downvoted questions, which part of them are closed as duplicates and part of them have accepted answers, but they are downvoted no matter if they are closed or have accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, **no**.

Child metas are designed to have no impact on reputation whatsoever. As a result, you can't use bounties to attract attention to your question. There are a few things you can do, however:

1. Post the question you asked in chat. Most of the active regulars are active there, and they can help you out.
2. Write a very catchy title for your question. Believe me, I had a couple of my questions top the hot questions list merely due to catchy titles. This is a very sure way to get attention.

Comment: While [good titles matter](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413/25301) (see also [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9327/25301)), we probably should avoid click-bait titles (i.e., suggestion 2 is probably a bad idea).